# AWS AMIs: RegisterImage vs CreateImage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What's the difference between [CreateImage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateImage.html) and [RegisterImage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RegisterImage.html)?

I mean,  If i create an AMI from an instance, I can launch this image at the moment. I don't understand what extra actions does RegisterImage

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**CreateImage** - You create an image from a EBS backed instance. This **API will automatically create snapshots** for the root and other volumes, **build an image automatically** with the snapshots. All you have to specify is the instance id and the API will figure out the rest.

- Prerequisites:

  - Nothing
- Specify:

  - InstanceId

You will get an exact clone of the instance.

---

**RegisterImage** - You **build the image manually**. You will create one or more snapshots manually from one or more instances. Then call the API with the snapshots you created, specify the architecture, kernel id, root device,  device mapping etc.,  Lot of flexibility in creating the image.

- Prerequisites:

  - Snapshots of the volumes
- Specify:

  - Architecture
  - Kernel ID
  - Root device
  - Device mappings

Answer (score 0):

RegisterImage is one of the process of CreateImage.

Once you create Image, this is the step that you must complete before you launch an instance.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a snapshot of an instance, you would use RegisterImage to create an AMI that you can then launch.